# Why timestamp value is diferrent in ibm jdk?

Tags: java, timestamp

Following is my java code snippet.

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("1900-12-31 23:59:59.999");
System.out.println("ts=====>" + ts.getTime());
```

**oracle jdk** result is

```
ts=====>-2177483400001
```

**ibm jdk(IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0)** result is

```
ts=====>-2177483272001
```

Why these two values are different?

Comment: At a guess, the two JDKs are treating them as different time zones.

Comment: @Powerlord I doubt it.  I don't know of any two time zones that are 128 seconds apart.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug that you should report to IBM.  The result that you say the IBM JVM gave you is obviously incorrect.  Unless there's some kind of 128 second time discontinuity that I've never heard of (similar to the famous 352 second discontinuity of 1927).

Comment: @DavidWallace How about timezones that are 353 seconds apart instead of 128? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result Actually OP's question is probably a duplicate of that one.

Comment: My previous comment implies that it's not a duplicate.